# I am using Object superclass in my code but it spits out an error constructor(int int) undefined

Tags: java, object

I created a class named `Huh2`. Then I defined Object types. It spits out an error saying: **"The constructor Huh2(int, int) is undefined"** when I run it.

Here is my code:

```
public class Huh2 {

    Object one;
    Object two;
    String trip;

    public Huh2(Object a, Object b)
    {
        one = a;
        two = b;
    }

    public void setone(Object a) {one=a;}
    public void setTwo(Object b) {two=b;}
    public Object getOne() {return one;}
    public Object getTwo() {return two;}
    public String getS() {return trip;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Huh2 ii = new Huh2(1,2);
        Object i = ii.getTwo();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: what java version are you working with

Comment: Did you save your file?

Answer (score 2):

if your are using Object class as normal primitive data type then it throw error because it's invalid type compatible with parameter, use wrapper class case of Object

Answer (score 1):

this here is the reason:

```
Huh2 ii=new Huh2(1,2);
```

the compiler can not promote the primitive to the equivalent wrapper class

pass objects intead of primitives

```
Huh2 ii=new Huh2(new Integer(1), new Integer(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The constructor Huh2(int, int) is undefined

at Huh2.main(Huh2.java:20)
```

It seems you are compiling with Java 1.4 (maybe compliance level set to 1.4 in the IDE/maven). If you compile with a newer version there won't be a problem because of the autoboxing feature introduced in Java 5. Here is a short description from [The Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

> Converting a primitive value (an int, for example) into an object of
>   the corresponding wrapper class (Integer) is called autoboxing. The
>   Java compiler applies autoboxing when a primitive value is:
>
> Passed as a parameter to a method that expects an object of the
>   corresponding wrapper class. Assigned to a variable of the
>   corresponding wrapper class.

Answer (score -2):

add this to your class

```
public Huh2(){
}
```

If you write any constructor, then compiler does not provided default no-arg constructor. You have to specify one. I think this will help you..